# CKEditor build custom version

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Here is my problem.

I have solution which uses customized version of CKEditor. In the solution I also have both full and minified version of CKEditor made month ago. Now, I want to make few more customizations of CKEditor, but I have a problem.

How can I create minified version of CKEditor by using full source code of CKBuilder on my machine? What do I need to download and where to copy it on my machine so that I can create minified version?

I was reading several posts stating that I need to clone git repository which contains build.sh script and then use CKBuilder tool. Problem is that I don't want to use GIT version of CKEditor source code, I want to use mine and I want it minified.

Any help on that?

Comment: How did you minify your customized version earlier? Your question seems a bit conflicted, why do you want to use CKBuilder now if you used a different minifier earlier? I think you need to properly plan the versioning and building system before you make any more customizations and then stick to that plan. It's rare to have to do customizations that can't be done with plugins and configuration, if you can I'd be very curious to hear what and why you have customized in the core? Forking active projects is difficult...

Comment: Let's just say that this knowledge of how it was done before is lost and gone now :). What I have now is customized CKEditor which needs to be customized more. Furthermore it's an older version of CKEditor and currently it's not an option to update to the current version. What is customized is not relevant since it is heavily connected to the rest of the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download the version of CKBuilder that was valid for your version of CKEditor: http://download.cksource.com/CKBuilder/. Which version was valid might be checked by viewing [build.sh in the ckeditor-dev repository](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/dev/builder/build.sh), of course make sure to switch to the proper tag first because the link I gave is to the latest version.
2. By looking at the same file figure out how to run CKBuilder (`java -jar ckbuilder.jar [OPTS]`). If you run it without args, it will display the list of available commands.
3. CKBuilder requires `build-config.js` to know which plugins to use, so make sure you have such. You can take the inspiration from the [ckeditor-presets](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-presets/tree/master/presets) repository.

Comment: Sounds just like what I need. As soon as I try it out I will mark your answer as accepted. Thank you for this mini guide!

Comment: I made it! Thanks a lot. Running command was simple: java -jar ckbuilder.jar -build SOURCEFOLDER DESTINATIONFOLDER and it worked like a charm. I have found proper ckbuilder.jar file by comparing release date of my CKEditor version with release date of CKBuilder and found appropriate one.